# Why isn't water thermal capacity used to easly cool the air in a room?

Tags: water, capacitance, air, cooling

Why isn't water thermal capacity used to easly cool the air in a room? Would it be energetically cheap to use cold water as a room air cooler and when the water temperature reaches some limit it is just replaced by new cold water from the pipe.Let say the volume of the container that holds the water is 5 litres...As the water has a large thermal capacity it should easly cool a room of 40 m3...(I am not asking about a device that would make the water evaporate into the room.)

Comment: it looks like a waste of water, which I assume you send to the sink

Comment: @Wolphramjonny the problem is as i understand therm.capacity of water how many times the water can be reused before it reaches a temperatue when it is no more convenient to use this same water and it should be replaced...

Comment: If you have a source of cold water, feel free. If you need to chill the water yourself it probably isn’t worth it. There is a long history of piling snow in the winter to use as a cold reservoir in the summer to increase refrigeration efficiency. Or storing ice (cut from ponds in the winter) to keep your ice box cold.

Comment: See a large scale application https://www.acciona.ca/projects/construction/port-and-hydraulic-works/deep-lake-water-cooling-system/